# How to use R's S3 object system for FizzBuzz?

Tags: r, oop

I do not understand how to use R's S3 object system. How can I write FizzBuzz using R's S3 object system?

Here is my implementation of the FizzBuzz algorithm:

```
fizzbuzz_s3 = function(input) {

  output = rep('', length(input))

  output[input %% 3 == 0] = paste(output[input %% 3 == 0], 'Fizz', sep = '')
  output[input %% 5 == 0] = paste(output[input %% 5 == 0], 'Buzz', sep = '')
  output[output == ''] = input[output == '']

  print(output)
}
```

Comment: This is like asking "How do I open a bottle of wine with a nutcracker?" I guess it's possible, but it's the wrong tool for the job. Any use of S3 would be pretty gratuitous.

Comment: @AllanCameron Tell my professor.

Answer (score 1):

I guess there are many ways to do this. In its simplest form you could probably just have two methods - an `as.fizzbuzz` to convert numeric vectors to a "fizzbuzz" class, and a `print.fizzbuzz` method.

```r
as.fizzbuzz <- function(x) {
  structure(x, class = "fizzbuzz")
}

print.fizzbuzz <- function(x, ...) 
{
  output <- as.character(x)
  output[x %% 3 == 0] <- "fizz"
  output[x %% 5 == 0] <- "buzz"
  output[x %% 5 == 0 & x %% 3 == 0] <- "fizzbuzz"
  print(output, quote = FALSE)
}
```

That means you could do:

```
x <- as.fizzbuzz(1:100)

x
#>   [1] 1        2        fizz     4        buzz     fizz     7        8       
#>   [9] fizz     buzz     11       fizz     13       14       fizzbuzz 16      
#>  [17] 17       fizz     19       buzz     fizz     22       23       fizz    
#>  [25] buzz     26       fizz     28       29       fizzbuzz 31       32      
#>  [33] fizz     34       buzz     fizz     37       38       fizz     buzz    
#>  [41] 41       fizz     43       44       fizzbuzz 46       47       fizz    
#>  [49] 49       buzz     fizz     52       53       fizz     buzz     56      
#>  [57] fizz     58       59       fizzbuzz 61       62       fizz     64      
#>  [65] buzz     fizz     67       68       fizz     buzz     71       fizz    
#>  [73] 73       74       fizzbuzz 76       77       fizz     79       buzz    
#>  [81] fizz     82       83       fizz     buzz     86       fizz     88      
#>  [89] 89       fizzbuzz 91       92       fizz     94       buzz     fizz    
#>  [97] 97       98       fizz     buzz
```